# How is the pka related to the ph of the solution for an amine?

Tags: acid-base, equilibrium

So was reading a magazine for competitive exams and this question is bugging me a lot.

[image]

How is pka values of a base associated with the pH of the solution. The solution for it is that the Nitrogens would remain this way and only the H from OH would be dissociated. That's obvious because the medium is basic and the acidic H would be dissociated, but what about the nitrogen atoms? How is the pka of a base represented? Is that the equilibrium constant for it's conjugate base?

Answer (score 1):

The pKa's quoted for the amine groups are for the protonated forms of the amines. The protonated forms would add a +1 charge to the molecule in solution. Since amines are fundamentally basic, the protonated amine is a *conjugate acid*.

Comment: But we use pka for bases too right? And how does it explain which amine will be protonated and which would not?

Comment: No the pKb value is for a base to accept a proton. For aqueous solutions: $$\mathrm{pKa + pKb = 14}$$

Comment: Ok I get that but how would you explain which amine will protonated and which not at a particular pH?

Comment: That is a different question which I side stepped on purpose. The short answer is that I would look at the information provided in the question (image). // The longer and more complicated answer is that histidine has  a side chain imidazole group. The imidazole group is a planar  aromatic heterocycle which is amphoteric. see the wikipeda article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imidazole

Comment: Hey in that article its written pka for imidazole and pka for its conjugate acid given separately. But you told that pka is only for acids and conjugate acids??

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henderson%E2%80%93Hasselbalch_equation

Comment: The neutral imidazole group (or molecule) can accept a proton or donate one. If both nitrogens are protonated then the cation formed has a +1 charge. If both nitrogens are deprotonated then the anion formed has a -1 charge.

Comment: A base accepting a proton won't represent the base dissociation constant, right? Because base dissociation constant involves donation of OH-

Comment: Sigh... $\ce{OH^{-}}$ is the base. $\ce{OH^{-}}$ accepts a proton from $\ce{H3O^{+}}$ to become $\ce{H2O}$.

Comment: Yeah that's the general equation for a base. The term Kb isn't used in this equation.